# Opening empty project with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, qgs

I am trying to open an empty project using PyQGIS:

[image]

All the answers I can find relate to already existing projects. i.e. they load a file like this:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('file.qgs')
```

I've tried passing no parameters/empty string to the read method, but with no effect. Looking at the methods that `QgsProject.instance()` provides, it doesn't seem like there is another method that would do this either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the [`newProject()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a556cb94a2fcb3b21004c405b847d32d1) method from the `QgisInterface` (`iface`) class

```py
iface.newProject()
```

Comment: The reason I could not find any answers is because no one asked it because it is too simple! Good to know that the iface makes this possible :-)